# Как в свойствах класса определить формат даты?

Tags: c#, дата

При инициализации класса я присваиваю значение даты. Хоть метод `DateTime.ParseExact` и корректно транслирует время, но в объекте класса DBnews он определяется по дефолту. В результате у меня записываются все нули. `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

```
DBnews dbnews = new DBnews();
dbnews.Date = DateTime.ParseExact("2015-07-08", "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture); 



 public abstract class News
    {...
        protected DateTime date;
    }....

    public class DBnews : News
    {
         public DateTime Date
        {
            get { return date; }
            set { date = value; }
        }

    }
```

Comment: в вашем коде не хватает `new`, кавычек и по разному названа переменная (`dbnews`/`dBnews`). Если это исправить - то все работает, по крайней мере в культуре en-US. В чем суть вопроса?

Comment: Как инициализировать `protected DateTime date` с форматом времени по умолчанию `yyyy-mm-dd`

Comment: Данный код работает для меня, в чем проблема?

Comment: 0001-01-01T00:00:00 вот что записывается в базу

Comment: Тогда там проблема в каком-то другом коде. У меня `Console.WriteLine(dbnews.Date);` выводит `7/8/2015 12:00:00 AM`.

Comment: как часы убрать оттуда? чтобы только yyyy/mm/dd

Comment: @Radzhab654654 никак. Это же тип DateTime, а не Date. Часы всегда присутствуют, просто в случае если вы используете только дату, составляющая времени содержит одни нули (ну или 12, если локаль английская).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы в базе хранилась только дата, нужно выбирать тип данных для поля в таблице Date, если это поддерживается базой данных.

Чтобы вывести тип DateTime без времени, например, на консоль можно записать так:

```
Console.WriteLine(dbnews.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

Если ваши классы спроектирвоаны таким образом, что при создании экземпляра идет сохранение в базу, то понятно почему пишется дата по умолчанию.

```
 DBnews dbnews = new DBnews();
 //запись в базу дергается в конструкторе
 dbnews.Date = DateTime.ParseExact("2015-07-08", "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture
```

В этом случае вам нужно передавать значение свойства Date в конструкторе и там инициализировать protected DateTime date.

```
public class DBnews : News
{
    public DBnews(DateTime date)
    {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public DateTime Date
    {
        get { return date; }
        set { date = value; }
    }
}

var dt = new DateTime(2015, 07, 08);
var dbnews = new DBnews(dt);
```

Кстати, проблема может быть и при самой вставке в базу.

В C# инициализировать тип даты можно и проще:

```
DBnews dbnews = new DBnews();
dbnews.Date = new DateTime(2015, 07, 08);
```